# MongoDB failed to start, Operation not permitted, on Docker Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-20.04

When trying to run MongoDB on a Ubuntu 20.04 server on docker I get the following error:

```
mongo-db | {"t":{"$date":"2023-07-04T20:09:49.620+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6384300, "ctx":"main","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"terminate() called. An exception is active; attempting to gather more information\n"}}
mongo-db | {"t":{"$date":"2023-07-04T20:09:49.620+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6384300, "ctx":"main","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"std::exception::what(): Operation not permitted\n**Actual exception type: std::system_error**\n\n"}}
mongo-db | {"t":{"$date":"2023-07-04T20:09:49.745+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31380,   "ctx":"main","msg":"BACKTRACE","attr":{"bt":{"backtrace":[{"a":"561069925924","b":"561064ACA000","o":"4E5B924","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.362","C":"mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::printStackTraceImpl(mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::Options const&, mongo::StackTraceSink*) [clone .constprop.362]","s+":"1F4"},{"a":"561069927E69","b":"561064ACA000","o":"4E5DE69","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","C":"mongo::printStackTrace()","s+":"29"},{"a":"5610699221B7","b":"561064ACA000","o":"4E581B7","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111myTerminateEv","C":"mongo::(anonymous namespace)::myTerminate()","s+":"D7"},{"a":"561069AACC46","b":"561064ACA000","o":"4FE2C46","s":"_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE","C":"__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)())","s+":"6"},{"a":"561069AACC81","b":"561064ACA000","o":"4FE2C81","s":"_ZSt9terminatev","C":"std::terminate()","s+":"11"},{"a":"561069AACDBB","b":"561064ACA000","o":"4FE2DBB","s":"__cxa_throw","s+":"4B"},{"a":"5610669FA02B","b":"561064ACA000","o":"1F3002B","s":"_ZSt20__throw_system_errori.cold.24","C":"std::__throw_system_error(int) [clone .cold.24]","s+":"2F"},{"a":"561069AC8FB9","b":"561064ACA000","o":"4FFEFB9","s":"_ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10unique_ptrINS_6_StateESt14default_deleteIS1_EEPFvvE","C":"std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())","s+":"29"},{"a":"5610679C43EA","b":"561064ACA000","o":"2EFA3EA","s":"_ZN5mongo27startSignalProcessingThreadENS_13LogFileStatusE","C":"mongo::startSignalProcessingThread(mongo::LogFileStatus)","s+":"11A"},{"a":"561066C0F71E","b":"561064ACA000","o":"214571E","s":"_ZN5mongo11mongod_mainEiPPc","C":"mongo::mongod_main(int, char**)","s+":"B4E"},{"a":"5610669FAD6E","b":"561064ACA000","o":"1F30D6E","s":"main","s+":"E"},{"a":"7FCCEA867D90","b":"7FCCEA83E000","o":"29D90","s":"__libc_init_first","s+":"90"},{"a":"7FCCEA867E40","b":"7FCCEA83E000","o":"29E40","s":"__libc_start_main","s+":"80"},{"a":"561066C0A025","b":"561064ACA000","o":"2140025","s":"_start","s+":"25"}],"processInfo":{"mongodbVersion":"6.0.7","gitVersion":"202ad4fda2618c652e35f5981ef2f903d8dd1f1a","compiledModules":[],"uname":{"sysname":"Linux","release":"4.4.0","version":"#1 SMP Tue Aug 25 11:59:26 MSK 2020","machine":"x86_64"},"somap":[{"b":"561064ACA000","elfType":3,"buildId":"CA53EC8680C99EC1221964D372EC35F9E6CEA6D9"},{"b":"7FCCEA83E000","path":"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6","elfType":3,"buildId":"69389D485A9793DBE873F0EA2C93E02EFAA9AA3D"}]}}},"tags":[]}
```

This is the docker-compose I am using:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    container_name: mongo-db
    image: mongo:latest
    networks:
      - mongo-backend


networks:
    mongo-backend:
        external: true
```

When trying to run this in the development environment it ran smoothly.
At first I had a data file set as the environment and thought that was the issue, regarding write rights. But even by removing them and cleaning the container, that did not work.

This is the version of Docker:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.7
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        f0df350
 Built:             Wed Jun  2 11:56:38 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.7
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       b0f5bc3
  Built:            Wed Jun  2 11:54:50 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.6
  GitCommit:        d71fcd7d8303cbf684402823e425e9dd2e99285d
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc95
  GitCommit:        b9ee9c6314599f1b4a7f497e1f1f856fe433d3b7
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

This is the first time I'm using MongoDB, setup for a friend, and any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing an selinux issue, which prevents MongoDB from starting. You can try to disable selinux by running `setenforce 0` on the host machine and then start the server again. This was suggested by an answer on [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186478/mongodb-refuse-to-start-operation-not-permitted)

Another possible reason is incorrect permissions or ownership of the /data/db directory or the file itself.
You can use the chown and chmod commands to change the owner and mode of the directory and the file, for example:

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db and sudo chmod -R 755 /data/db
```

Also, this error may be caused by Docker settings that limit the capabilities of the container running MongoDB. You can use the `--cap-add` option to grant additional capabilities to the container, for example:

```
docker run --cap-add SYS_ADMIN mongo:latest
```

You can also use the `--privileged` option to give the container full access to the host resources, for example:

```
docker run --privileged mongo:latest
```

Comment: I think Selinux is not enabled here. When I run the command I get "Command not found".

Comment: Umm, so you mean you haven't installed SELinux or AppArmor? If so, I updated my answer, else please let me know.

Comment: Hey Victor, first of all, thanks for assisting!
I have tried the options you gave, and the last option you gave (--privileged) resulted in:
```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: process_linux.go:508: setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused: resulting devices cgroup doesn't match target mode: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```
While the second option (--cap-add) gave the original error described above.

Comment: You may still try the other solutions, such as updating your `containerd` and `Docker` packages, or using a different runtime for your `MongoDB` container.